# Screen is splitted when I rotate the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm developing an Android app with Android Studio and the emulator. In the last months, I notice that when I rotate the emulator to the app behaviour in landscape mode, the screen is splitted.

[image: the problem]

It's not a problem of my application, I tried with Gmail app and other and the problem persists.

I tried to change OpenGL config but nothing changes. I'm working on a Mac Book Pro with Big Sur. Any idea about to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create a brand-new virtual device in the emulator and see .. I had similar issue and the problem was in the virtual device itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did face the same issue:

[image]

Recreating/Resizing Emulator did not help.

To fix it, I just clicked the zoom button and everything is working as intended.

Zoom option:

[image]

After clicking zoom, it works:

[image: After clicking zoom it works]

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the AVD worked for me, just drag the corners to make the AVD smaller or bigger. After resizing it the split screen should go back to normal. If the problem persists try making a new AVD.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried to resize the emulator's window but nothing changes.

Comment: If you update to android studio 4.1(you probably already did) you can enable the emulator to be run inside Android Studio instead of a separate application. Check the box in the settings(under tools - emulator) and when rotating the emulator in android studio the problem no longer occurs for me at all. If that doesn't work, I'm all out of suggestions.